# table.cell[].innerText works in IE but not in mozilla

Tags: javascript

Javascript

```
function test(){
var tableToSort = document.getElementById('tblid');
    for (i=1; i < tableToSort.rows.length; i++)
          {
            alert("result ============> "+tableToSort.cells(iCurCell).innerText);
            iCurCell = iCurCell + tableToSort.cols;
          }
}
```

Upper function not works in IE but not in mozilla so i have change it with

```
function test(){
    var tableToSort = document.getElementById('tblid');
        for (i=1; i < tableToSort.rows.length; i++)
              {
        alert("result ============> "+tableToSort.rows[iCurCell1].cells[2].textContent);
                iCurCell = iCurCell + tableToSort.cols;
              }
    }
```

In mozilla for first record of loop it works fine but for other it prints `undefined`.
While in IE all records print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`innerText` property is only for IE, see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText), use `textContent` for most of browser including IE9.

Answer (score 0):

you should really look for the textNode inside the tablecell:
inside your for:

```
 var tcell = tableToSort.rows[iCurCell1].cells[2];
 var child = tcell.firstChild;
 do {
    if(child.nodeType == 3)
       break;
 } while(child = child.nextSibling);
 var textThatYouWant = child.nodeValue;
```

this is the true DOM implementation that will work with all browsers